# How to disable multi-select-component in ember-widgets

Tags: select, ember.js, multiple-select

Is there any way to disable the multi-select-component from addepar's ember-widgets?

This works for the single `select-component`

```
{{select-component
  contentBinding="selectCountries"
  prompt="Select a Country"
  value=selectSelected
  disabled=true
}}
```

The same does not work for the `multi-select-component`

```
{{multi-select-component
  contentBinding="selectCountries"
  prompt="Select a Country"
  selections=multiSelectSelected
  disabled=true
}}
```

Here's a not-working [JS bin](http://jsbin.com/subekubi/5/edit?html,js,output) example. I looked through the source code, there doesn't seem to be an option for this.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I could think of doing it, short of editing the source code was this (updated [JS bin](http://jsbin.com/subekubi/7/edit)):

I defined an Ember component that takes an array of strings (`selections`) as its only parameter. I used all the classes that are used by the `multi-select-component` so I didn't have to redefine all the CSS:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/disabled-multi-select">
  <div class="ember-view ember-select multi-select-disabled" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="ember-select-container ember-select-multi dropdown-toggle js-dropdown-toggle">
      <ul class="form-control ember-select-choices">
        {{#each selection in selections}}
        <li class="ember-view ember-select-search-choice">
          <div>{{selection}}</div>
          <div class="ember-select-search-choice-close">×</div>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Then I added some css to make it look like a disabled select:

```
.ember-select.multi-select-disabled > .ember-select-container > .form-control {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #EEE;
  opacity: 1;
}
.ember-select.multi-select-disabled > .ember-select-container .ember-select-search-choice {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.ember-select.multi-select-disabled > .ember-select-container .ember-select-search-choice .ember-select-search-choice-close {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.ember-select.multi-select-disabled > .ember-select-container .ember-select-search-choice .ember-select-search-choice-close:hover {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
```

It's used like this:

```
{{#if isInputDisabled}}
  // Stick your multi-select-component in here
{{else}}
  {{disabled-multi-select selections=multiSelectSelected}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Turns out it's a [bug](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-widgets/issues/94) that I might need to fix